# How to convert JSON file into PO?

Tags: node.js, json, translate, po

Hello friends and colleagues...
A quick question How do Iconvert JSON file into PO?
I had a PO file with relevant translations, then I converted it to JSON on some website after that wrote a little script in NodeJS to translate keys via Google translate API and now I just want to convert this translated JSON back to PO...
Is there any easy way? I don't seem to find any working npm packages or anything else...
Please Help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Online tools like https://localise.biz/free/converter/po-to-json can help.
To translate using command line there's an open source repo on Git- https://github.com/2gis/i18n-json-po